# Missing components in material google library on Android

Tags: java, android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I am trying to use `SwitchMaterial` component within an Android project, however Android studio cannot find it at design time, and including it within my xml layouts causes a `ClassNotFoundException` at runtime.

- Recent Android studio project so is already setup using AndroidX
- `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` is in my dependencies and gradle syncs with no errors
- Some other Material components are present, eg I am using `MaterialButton` on the same XML/Activity
- Unable to find `com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial` in xml
- Unable to import `com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial` when trying to add to activity java unit
- Build settings :  Compile SDK = 29 Build Tools = 29.0.2 Min SDK = 19 Target SDK = 29
- There are no proguard rules setup (At all) so should not be messing with it
- Spent an hour googling answers - nothing on SO, or the Android / Material Docs

**Cannot find `SwitchMaterial` even though other components are there**
[image: Missing Components]

**app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        lintConfig file("lint.xml")
        showAll false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

**XML layout**

```xml
        <com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
            android:id="@+id/login_notificationsSwitchFamily"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Family Friendly"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_16" />
```

Any help is appreciated. I cannot see why there would be missing components.

Comment: Looking through the [history](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commits/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/switchmaterial/SwitchMaterial.java) of the [`SwitchMaterial.java`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/switchmaterial/SwitchMaterial.java) file on GitHub, you can see that the class was introduced in `1.1.0-alpha01`: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/56ee534de239cd93a5eae894abb9138e7816e134#diff-ef5b3b2325133d0f0119115f255bd0e7

Comment: Cheers Edric, as Gabriele suggested below I am using the 1.1.0-beta01 now which has added the complete list. Thanks for checking though. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the version **1.1.0** of the material components library.

Currently

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele. Worked a charm, it messed with some of my styles on other Material components, but I can figure that out, at least I have all the components listed in the docs now! Cheers!